# Devise Test Helper - sign_in does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

For some reason, I can not get the devise helper method sign_in to work. current_user keeps on being null. Any idea what the problem could be?

Test:

```
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all subscribers as @subscribers" do
      subscriber = @user.subscribers.create! valid_attributes
      get :index
      assigns(:subscribers).should eq([subscriber])
    end
  end
```

Implementation:

```
  def index
    @subscribers = current_user.subscribers.all    <------- ERROR

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @subscribers }
    end
  end

Error:
 NoMethodError:
       undefined method `subscribers' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you solved this, judging by your code.  I have had this happen before, and for some reason it gets me every time.

The rspec/rails scaffold for controller specs won't work with Devise::TestHelpers out of the box.

```
get :index, {}, valid_session
```

The valid_session call overwrites the session stuff that Devise sets up.  Remove it:

```
get :index, {}
```

This should work!

Comment: yup, that was the problem! Thanks! :)

Comment: At first I thought this didn't work because I tried it in a `pry` debug session and it failed. Exiting pry and setting it up, it then worked for me.

Comment: What file are you exactly talking about?

Comment: @d34th4ck3r: `your_controller_spec.rb`.  It should be mentioned that this answer is pretty much expired.  With rspec-rails 3.3, rails 4.x there is no such conflict.

Answer (score 22):

If you include the `Confirmable` module in your `User` model (or other devise-authenticatable model), then the test `@user` you create must be confirmed for the `sign_in` to take effect:

```
before :each do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  @user.confirm!
  sign_in @user
end
```

(I see that this wasn't your issue, but perhaps another reader shall benefit from it.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I have been tearing my hear out trying to figure out why 'sign_in' wasn't working in my tests.

Comment: FYI for readers: 'confirm!' has been deprecated; you should use 'confirm' instead.

Comment: @rbonick I couldn't get either `confirm!` or ``confirm` to work. I took the whole line out and my tests still pass though using *this* answer. I'm not sure what to make of that. Is that ok to do?

Comment: I've been strugling all day with this. but my fix was to set `confirmed_at { Time.now }` on factory girl

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well, unfortunately this is never mentioned in the documentation. Maybe a new PR is in order.

Answer (score 5):

For versions of Devise 4.2.0+, the `Devise::TestHelpers` have been deprecated. Instead, `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` should be used.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

[changelog](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#420---2016-07-01)

---

For the spec, make sure to `include Devise::TestHelpers`. To make it easy, in my **spec/spec_helper.rb**, I have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

which automatically includes it for all controller specs.

Also, you need to do this to get sign_in to work:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
get :new
```

It is probably best to add `@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]` to your before(:each). (Note you can do this in your config if you don't want to do this for every controller).

---

For the `current_user` part, make sure you have a model `User`, where you call `devise`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # call devise to define user_signed_in? and current_user
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  # though you don't have to include all these modules
end
```

Devise uses the call in the User model to define `user_signed_in?` and `current_user` in your controllers. The reason is that if you have:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise
end
```

then Devise will have methods `admin_signed_in?` and `current_admin` defined.

Comment: thanks for your help. I added the Devise::TestHelpers - it did not make a difference :/ My user model does call devise. I could host my project on git hub - it has just started so it doesnt really have much code in it ...

Comment: if `current_user` is nil, it can also indicate that no user is signed in (for the 2nd problem).

Comment: You also need to set the request env devise mapping (added to answer). All the information I got from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers, I just forgot about the devise mapping when I answered at first.

Comment: i just tried adding @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user] - it did not work either :/ I have updated my git repository with your answer.

Comment: the current_user is nil - maybe you are right - no user is signed in. That indicates that it might be the devise sign_in helper problem

Comment: That's because you added the Devise mappings statement AFTER the sign_in method. It needs to be before you sign in!

Comment: ah - i was really hoping your suggestion would work, but moving the devise mapping before signing in didn't make a difference :/ (updated on git)

Comment: can't think of any other possible cause. I know it should work because it works on my own application... . What is the error you get? Is it method not defined? or sign_in has no effect? or what?

Comment: the error is on the question: undefined method `subscribers' for nil:NilClass.

i was wondering, did you clone my repository? maybe you could see if rspec runs on your machine. I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: well, took a long time to download everything on my capped internet connection (gems take a while). `rspec` passes all tests.

Comment: According to the doc, defining `@request.env["devise.mapping"]` is necessary only "if you are testing Devise internal controllers or a controller that inherits from Devise's."

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when trying to test that an SSO endpoint I was writing was creating an session for a user. Since it only applied to one test, I just needed to add the following block before my test

```
  before do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => email, :password => "password")
    user.confirm!
  end

  it "should create and session for the user and redirect to home page" do
```