# session hash does not persist on rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, tdd

In my people_controller_spec.rb I have

```
before(:each) do
    @office = FactoryGirl.create(:office)
    @organization = FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, organization: @organization)

    @request.session['user_id'] = @user.id
    @request.session['current_organization_id'] = @user.organization.id
  end
```

and I have this application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_organization
    if session[:current_organization_id]
      Organization.find(session[:current_organization_id])
    else
      @current_organization ||= Organization.find(current_user.organization_id)
    end
  end

  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :current_organization
end
```

The session hash does not seem to persist inside the application_controller.rb that is why I get these kinds of test errors where @current_user in the application_controller.rb is nil

```
  6) PeopleController index sorts all people alphabetically by first_name
     Failure/Error: get :index, {search: {meta_sort: "first_name.asc"}}, valid_session
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `organization_id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `current_organization'
     # ./app/controllers/people_controller.rb:107:in `get_orgs'
     # ./spec/controllers/people_controller_spec.rb:71:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have already done everything but failed.

I use rails (3.2.9) and rspec-rails 2.12.2

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM AFTER SEEING THIS [Devise Test Helper - sign_in does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226502/devise-test-helper-sign-in-does-not-work)

I just removed all the "valid_session" method call.

Answer (score 5):

In your `before :each` block set the session with:

```
session[:user_id] = @user.id
session[:current_organization_id] = @user.organization.id
```

This uses the session helper provided by the rspec controller macros. Also I'm not sure if the session is a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` like `params` but either way its good to keep to using the same key type.

Comment: Ah - I should have asked to see the test itself. Something to keep in mind for devise too :)